# multiple mysql connections on one page php

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am getting errors (not really errors, just not working properly) and I'm trying to figure out if it's related to my sql connections. I have 2 separate connections to two entirely different databases.

```
$dshost = "kjbkb";
$dsdatabase = "kjhk";
$dsusername = "hjgfytdf";
$dspassword = "jhv";
mysql_connect($dshost,$dsusername,$dspassword);
mysql_select_db($dsdatabase) or die( "Unable to select database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '".$_POST['paydl']."'";
$cheeseburger = mysql_query($sql);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($cheeseburger);
$autobus_user = $res['id'];

mysql_close(); //close first connection

$db_host = "khgv";
$db_user = "trdstx";
$db_password = "txz";
$db_database = "gfxx";
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die("Unable to connect to host");
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$ASDFASDF = "SELECT * FROM `autobus` WHERE `user_id` = '".$autobus_user."' LIMIT 3";
$BobDoleDontNeedThis = mysql_query($ASDFASDF);
$resnumbatwo = mysql_fetch_array($BobDoleDontNeedThis);

mysql_close(); //close 2nd connection
```

Am I doing this right? Why is `$resnumbatwo` returning false?

Comment: No, you're not doing this correctly. You're using a deprecated library. Your code is wide open to SQL injection. You really need to look up `mysqli` as a minimum...

Comment: thanks but i'm well aware it's depreciated. do you have an actual answer to my question?

Comment: Yes, I do have an answer. You need to handle your MySQL resources as well. Basically, you need to assign the connections and pass them in as resource references to the functions. `mysql_fetch_array` will also return `false` if there are no records matched by the query. The question of course is why you're using an old standard and insecure code?

Comment: From the manual: *«Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.»*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` will return `false` if there are no matching records returned from the query. Please see the following entry from the [API reference docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> ### Return Values:
>
> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, **or
>   `FALSE` if there are no more rows**. The type of returned array
>   depends on how result_type is defined. By using `MYSQL_BOTH`
>   (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number
>   indices. Using `MYSQL_ASSOC`, you only get associative indices (as
>   [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) works), using `MYSQL_NUM`, you only get number
>   indices (as [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) works).

Comment: ultimately this was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

When using multiple MySQL connections in PHP, you have to supply a fourth argument telling PHP to actually create new connections like this (this is very important, if you are using two connections to the same host):

```
$db1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $passwd1, true);
$db2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $passwd2, true);
```

If the fourth argument is not used, and the parameters are the same, then PHP will return the same link and no new connection will be made.

After this you should use "mysql_query" with an extra parameter than defines which connection to use:

```
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db1) or die(mysql_error($res1));
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2, $db2) or die(mysql_error($res2));
```

The description of the fourth parameter from php.net is:
"*If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.*"

See more at:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Better save each connection handler in a variable and transmit it to correspondent `mysql_query()`.

*Example:*

```
$dbch1 = mysql_connect($dshost, $dsusername, $dspassword);
$dbch2 = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

$cheeseburger = mysql_query($sql, $dbch1);
$BobDoleDontNeedThis = mysql_query($ASDFASDF, $dbch2);
```

Comment: Please also be aware that `mysql_fetch_array` will return `false` if there are no matching records.

Comment: @BenM I didn't know that. thank you, that may have been the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$dbch1 = mysql_connect($dshost, $dsusername, $dspassword,true);
$dbch2 = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password,true);

$cheeseburger = mysql_query($sql, $dbch1);
$BobDoleDontNeedThis = mysql_query($ASDFASDF, $dbch2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php7 
you can use the mysqli_change_user() function.

Like in the examples at the php.net page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.change-user.php